# Find Median of DateDiff Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff, median

I have this as my Average Statement and am wanting to get the Median Value:

select AVG (DATEDIFF("m", dlg_applicationreceived, dlg_dateofdecision)) as TimetakenAVG,
format(dlg_dateofdecision, 'MMM-yy') as MonthDate
from dlg_ast
group by format(dlg_dateofdecision, 'MMM-yy')
order by format(dlg_dateofdecision, 'MMM-yy')

I've played around with some of the previous answers to Median Questions, but can't get mine to work correctly.

Any help would be most appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I voted to close as duplicate because the link has several methods you can try to compute the median. SQL Server, like most other databases, does not have a built in median function.

Comment: Ok will keep trying,  it's the DateDiff part that is complicating it.   I cant see an answer using DateDiff and grouping.

Comment: Try one of the methods and if you get stuck, then comment here and someone can reopen the question.

Comment: I got this part to work with a Median result, but just one, I want to group it by the 'format(ass.dlg_dateofdecision, 'MM-yy') so that I have one Median result per month.    SELECT x.MedianAnswer

FROM   (SELECT (DATEDIFF("m", ass.dlg_applicationreceived, ass.dlg_dateofdecision)) as ss, 
               Count(1) OVER (partition BY 'A')        AS TotalRows, 
               Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY(DATEDIFF("m", ass.dlg_applicationreceived, ass.dlg_dateofdecision)) ASC) AS MedianAnswer
        FROM   dlg_ass ass) x 

WHERE  x.MedianAnswer = Round(x.TotalRows / 2.0, 0)